# Trying to validate a folder being dynamically created using PHP

Tags: php, validation, directory

I am trying validate: whether or not the folder I am attempting to create exists. Sure, I get a message... an error message :/ telling me it does! (if it doesn't exist, no error message, and everything goes as planned).

It outputs this error message

```
Directory exists

Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /home/***/public_html/***/formulaires/processForm-test.php on line 75

UPLOADS folder has NOT been created
```

The current code I use is this one:

```
$dirPath = $_POST['company'];  

if(is_dir($dirPath))
  echo 'Directory exists';
else
  echo 'directory not exist';

function ftp_directory_exists($ftp, $dirPath) 
{ 
    // Get the current working directory 
    $origin = ftp_pwd($ftp); 

    // Attempt to change directory, suppress errors 
    if (@ftp_chdir($ftp, $dirPath)) 
    { 
        // If the directory exists, set back to origin 
        ftp_chdir($ftp, $origin);    
        return true; 
    } 

    // Directory does not exist 
    return false; 
} 


$result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);  
if ($result == 1) {  
    echo '<br/>'.$dirPath . " has been created".'<br/>';
} else {  
    echo '<br/>'.$dirPath . " has NOT been created".'<br/>';
}
```

I added the middle part recently (I don't know if that would even have an impact). The one that starts off with "function ftp_directory_exists($ftp, $dirPath)"

Answer (score 1):

Use [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) to check if a file / directory exists:

```
if(!file_exists('/path/to/your/directory')){

//yay, the directory doesn't exist, continue

}
```

Comment: I was playing around with your snippet and washi's as well. One of the things that confused the crap out of me more than anything is the path.

My forms AND uplaoded pics are found here:
/mysite.com/formulaires

So, would the path be written like this?  With the slashes in that order?

Comment: Something like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/mysite.com/formulaires'`

Comment: Mmm, still a no go. The same error keeps appearing. I had to modify the snippet, or else it would give me a parse error. After that was fixed, the old error came back.

Answer (score 1):

The function ftp_directory_exists you added won't have any impact on your code as it is never called...

You might tried something like this (not tested...) :

```
$dirPath = $_POST['company'];  
$dirExists = is_dir($dirPath);

if(!dirExists)
    $dirExists = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);  

echo '<br/>'.$dirPath . (($dirExists)? "" : "DO NOT") . " exists".'<br/>';
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work per se. I mean, the output is good of course, yet I still get the same error message. I could either suppress the error message (but I have no clue how, and not the right thing to do imo). Or, to fix the code lol, but damn, that's proving to be a pain.